# Two divs with dynamic width together

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a header with a search input and the name of the user next to each other. As the name of the user can be very long, the search input has to vary its width (as well as the username div).  Like the image below:

[image: dynamic width]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left" style="width: 80%">DYNAMIC WIDTH - search input</div>
  <div class="right" style="width: 20%">SHORT NAME</div>
</div>
```

**codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ihmgi).**

I'm setting the width manually there (80% and 20%, or 70% and 30%), I want it to change dynamically according to the name's length and both div's have to sum 100%.

It looks very simple but I can't think of a way of doing it.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve, not very clear?

Comment: perhaps what you want is style `display:inline-block`?

Comment: sorry, Harry, I'll edit the question to be more clear. But, as you can see, I'm setting the width manually there (80% and 20%), I want it to change dynamically according to the name's length

Comment: @Kyojimaru `display: inline-block` didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It easier to set them as `display: table-cell` elements, since cells adjust their width to fit the parent.

If you set the `left` div to `width: 100%` it will always take the remaining space left by `right` div:

http://jsfiddle.net/fzmj5q2r/

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    display: table-cell;
    background: green;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use an ellipsis if the text is too long in the left part ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the margins to auto? Like so:

```
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;">Sample Text</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work... Both div's together (name and search input) have to sum 100%.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/stephenbe/pen/KhDJw

All I did was have a wrap, inside your input and name ...name is over the input text

Tell me if this is a solution that works for you

```
.name {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  background:red;

  padding:20px;
  vertical-align:middle;

  box-sizing:border-box;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stephen. But I don't know if you realized your .name div is over the input. So if I put a long string in the input field it's gonna be hidden by the red .name div.

Comment: Yep, like the table-cell solution better! Glad you ended up finding your answer :)